# Does raspberry 4 need cooling?

Tags: pi-4, cooling

I got RPi 4 (4GB), with official case and power supply, updated to latest eeprom

```
BCM2711 detected
Dedicated VL805 EEPROM detected
BOOTLOADER: up-to-date
CURRENT: Thu Apr 16 17:11:26 UTC 2020 (1587057086)
 LATEST: Thu Apr 16 17:11:26 UTC 2020 (1587057086)
 FW DIR: /lib/firmware/raspberrypi/bootloader/critical
VL805: up-to-date
CURRENT: 000137ad
 LATEST: 000137ad
```

and installed OpenMediaVault https://www.openmediavault.org/

I'll be using it as a NAS with 1 or 2 USB3 HDDs.

Even without case top, and no load, my RPi is running at a temperature of 52C or more. This looks a bit too much.
I've watched some videos by ExplainingComputers about cooling RPi 4: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AVfvhEJ9XD0 and now I'm thinking that official case is very bad. Should I get a passive cooling case in a NAS scenario? Or just keep the lead off (I don't like this idea)?

Comment: I would definitely recommend _not_ putting the Pi 4 in a official case. They were literally designed to overheat the Pi. At least get a heatsink and or fan.

Comment: For my personal use of my Pi 4, I like having the Pi in a case, so that it does not get dusty. But, I always have a fan ready to run in case the case warms up.

Comment: I will also say that the Pi does not _need_ cooling (The Pi will automatically throttle to reduce temperture), but it's highly **recommended** cause it will make it faster and last longer.